# Arrays cannot be half of a number

Tags: c++, arrays

An array cannot have a declarated size of half right? So this isn't possible correct?

```
 arrayA[1.5];
```

Comment: What's `arrayA`? In C++ you could have some overloaded operator for `[]` that takes a `float` or `double` and performs meaningful work.

Comment: If you explain the reasons why you want an array with 1.5 elements, and what you expect those elements to be, perhaps we can give you standard solutions to what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear. I am just asking if it is possible to have a size declaration of a half when working with arrays. I was just wondering if it was possible or not.

Comment: How would you store half an object? The size of the array is the number of objects that it holds, there is no such thing as half an object.

Comment: Like I say, explain *why* you want this, and *what behaviour* you might expect.  It is not legal to declare an array with a non-integer size.  Do you, for example, want the compiler to read your mind and maybe give you three elements which are indexed 0.0, 0.5, and 1.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct:

> > > 8.3.4 Arrays
> > >       In a declaration `T D` where `D` has the form
> > >       `D1 [constant-expression opt ]`
> > >       and the type of the identifier in the declaration `T D1` is “derived-declarator-type-list `T`,” then the type of the
> > >       identifier of `D` is an array type. `T` is called the array element type; this type shall not be a reference type, the
> > >       (possibly cv-qualified) type void, a function type or an abstract class type. If the constant-expression
> > >       (5.19) is present, it shall be an **integral** constant expression and its value shall be greater than zero.
> > >
> > > *(INTERNATIONAL
> > >       STANDARD ISO/IEC 14882 Second edition 2003-10-15, emphasis added)*